# Understanding chapter 3.1 (Laplace's equation) in Introduction to electrodynamics Griffiths 4 ed

Tags: electrostatics, computational-physics, algorithms

I really need help to understand chapter 3.1.
What is the method of relaxation?
How can I use the method of relaxation to solve Laplace's equation?
How can I use the first and second uniqueness theories to solve Laplace's equation?

Comment: Relevant https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/310447/

Comment: This might get closed for clarity, could you specify what about it you don't understand exactly?